# forloop, iterators and vectors doesn't cooperate with me

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Why does this work fine for me:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        os << vec[i] << " ";
    }
```

while this doesn't:

```
 for(vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); it++)
    {
        os << vec[*it] << " ";
    }
```

Comment: Consider `const_iterator` for printing. Also, when used like this, C++11's ranged-for is a better solution.

Comment: How exactly is it "not working"?  Not enough times through the loop, or crashing because of the `vec[*it]` call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be printing `*it` instead of using it as the index and you should probably change the condition to `it != vec.end()`.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis I'm just a beginner and I've never seen `it < v.end()` in serious code. Good to know.

Comment: The difference is that `it != v.end()` works for all container types, because `==` is defined for all iterator types. `<` is only defined for random access iterators; it works here because `vector`'s iterators are random access. It wouldn't work for `list`.

Comment: While the end condition is *correct* I would not recommend using it, but rather the more idiomatic `it != vec.end()`. The comparison with `<` works only on random access iterators, while the test for equality will work with any iterator.

Comment: @cnicutar are you being sarcastic? look at your rep again 0o

Comment: @Mr.Anubis From the FAQ: *Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you*. I am not being sarcastic and I *am* just a beginner.

Comment: @cnicutar if you're beginner then I must be unborn :P

Comment: A beginner with a Guru badge ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You're using the iterator wrong, it should be:

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); it++)
{
    os << *it << " ";
}
```

Your code just attempts to print the element at index `*it`, which might not even be valid.